# Stream.ReadString returns one result while using StreamReader.ReadToEnd returns string.Empty and both are wrong

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

I've got a code which populates a stream. After population, the stream's length 1000 (for instance), while the returned string length from Stream.ReadString is 997 and the returned value from StreamReader.ReadToEnd() is an empty stream.

Here's a code showing what I mean (obviously, this isn't exactly my working code, but the issue is the same):

```
MemoryStream stream = MethodCreatingPopulatedStream(stream);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

if (stream.Length != reader.ReadToEnd().Length)
{
    PostQuestionInStackOverFlow();
}
else if (!string.Equals(reader.ReadToEnd(), stream.ReadString()))
{
    PostQuestionInStackOverFlow();
    GetAnnoyedAtDotNet();
}
else
{
    Smile();
}
```

What am I missing here?

P.S, Adding Stream.Flush anywhere made no change

Comment: Kent has covered most of it - but after you've called `ReadToEnd` in the first block, there's nothing more to be read from either the stream or the reader, because both are positioned at the end of the stream. Maybe you should post some *real* code as a short but complete program which actually compiles and demonstrates the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the string (characters) is not necessarily the same length as the stream (bytes). It depends entirely on the encoding and any other overhead associated with storing a string (such as storing its length).

As for your second test, `stream.ReadString()` doesn't even exist and would have to assume a certain encoding if it did.

Comment: ReadString is a DevExpress extension methods, didn't notice the dll from which I took it, sorry.

Comment: @Neowizard: And what encoding does it use? And what data have you actually got in the first place? Your question is unclear in terms of why you'd *expect* any other results.

Comment: I expected the string length to be the same as the size of string I extract from it, but @Kent explained the mistake there.

Comment: Correction, I meant "Stream length" in my previous comment. Also, to note, the stream contains textual data which I placed there in another flow of the application (using StreamWritere.Write(string))